# The correct way to construct a Map in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, constructor, setter, getter

I'm trying to create a mutable Map in a backing bean that can be used globally. Here's how I'm using it:

```
private Map<Object, Date> myMap;

public void myMethod(){
      getMyMap().put(myObject, myDate);
    //I have also tried the following with the same results:
    //myMap.put(myObject, myDate);
}

//setter
public void setMyMap(Map<Object, Date> myMap) {
      this.myMap= myMap;
}

//getter
public Map<Object, Date> getMyMap() {
    return myMap;
}
```

The setter and getter for myMap is automatically generated from the program I'm using (autogen'd sets and gets work for everything else).

The error come's when I try to populate the Map. It returns a null pointer exception.  The code is obviously simplified, but if you need more information, I'd be glad to give it.

My problem has been solved by using the following:

```
    private Map<Object, Date> myMap = new HashMap<Object, Date>();

public void myMethod(){
    myMap.put(myObject, myDate);
}
```

If anyone has more advice, I'd be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: You let `myMap` null... hence the null pointer exception.

Comment: From where are you injecting the value of `myMap`? Or are you really injecting before accessing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that `setMyMap` gets called? As if it doesn't, then the `myMap` will be `null` when it gets used.

If you want the map to have a "default" value, you should initialise it like this:

```
private Map<Object, Date> myMap = new HashMap<Object, Date>();
```

Comment: This is what solved my issue, although djechlin gave sound advice.  My code is cleaned and working.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm nearly positive you have a design flaw here.  It's very rare to offer a getter and setter for a `map`.  You should probably take the `map` as a constructor argument and expose `put` and `get` methods instead.  This will clean up the possibility of this error for instance.

Comment: Although this did not solve my issue completely, you gave good advice.  I've cleaned my code up a bit.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<Object, Date> myMap;
```

because `myMap` is pointing to `null`

1) You need to do setMyMap before updating mmap

(or)

2) Change map declaration to

```
private Map<Object, Date> myMap = new HashMap<Object, Date>();
```

Comment: I think you mean `private Map<Object, Date> myMap = new HashMap<Object, Date>();` as there is no constructor which takes class types.

Answer (score 0):

The variable myMap is going to be null until you set it using setMyMap(newMap)